# On iOS, ion-input types characters into void except the first

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, user-input

In my Ionic 3.20 + cordova ios 4.5.4 app compiled against XCode 9.4.1, text fields `<ion-input>` as below are only accepting 1 character and then the iOS keyboard keeps accepting characters... into void.

`<ion-input placeholder="User Name" [(ngModel)]="userName" type="text" clearInput></ion-input>`

Same problem appears on real iPhone 7, Safari, and in the XCode simulator

Comment: Does the `ion-input` moves the cursor but the characters are invisible?

Comment: No cursor actually displays (even by re-cliking, re-re-clicking and re-re-re-clicking within the field) and the text returned to the app retains only the single visible char that I managed to type

Comment: I encountered that problem months ago when I accidentally styled one of the elements with `z-index`. The behavior was like, the keyboard pushes the element with `z-index` upward so the input field value becomes invisible after 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

A `z-index` was causing the input field to disappear on iOS, as suggested by @Mystery.

I've reduced the scope of the guilty CSS rule so that it does not apply to `ion-input`.